# Oracle ADF Form Data was Not adding to DB

Tags: mysql, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am developing a web application using Oracle ADF, jDeveloper and MySql. I have created an Entity Object and based on this Entity Object I have created a View Object. In one of my pages I have drag and drop my view object as Adf Form. I have inserted "create Insert" and "commit" buttons. Create Insert is working fine means it is creating a new empty form, the problem is after entering data into empty form when I click commit button data is not inserted into Db.

And I have created a new application and in that I have done the same thing as mentioned above. The same thing is working in my new application.

Please help me....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Any errors in the log window of WebLogic?
If you put a breakpoint before the commit action in the binding layer - do you actually hit it at runtime?
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/introduction_to_the_adf_debugger

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time Shay. No errors in the log window of WebLogic.

Comment: "If you put a breakpoint before the commit action in the binding layer - do you actually hit it at runtime?" - I did not use break points. Hitting commit run time means ? Actually I dropped a commit action from DC to a jsff and I run that. When page loads I am trying to insert some data and trying to commit. Commit is not happing.

Comment: Yeah, Shay I tried putting a breakpoint before the commit action in the binding layer and I am able to hit it at run time. Even now also data is not inserted into DB.

Answer (score 0):

Test your AM with  AMTester , try to do commit after entering data.
check your Log. if this is working fine.

2) check the source on commit operation ,post the code on commit operation

Comment: ya thanks for your time. AMTester inserting data into DB. But from browser commit is not inserting data to DB. Commit operation code                                               <af:commandButton actionListener="#{bindings.Commit.execute}" text="Commit" id="cb2"
                                  binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_administrtion_AddKpi.cb2}"/>

Comment: 1) FromThe Dc just drag that VO to New JspX page as Table 2) from The  Dc  there is commit operation just drag this Operation as Adf button and try once again